# Attention to vs attention on

Tags: prepositions

I have seen both *to* and *on* after the word *attention*. Is there any rule, when to choose one over another ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, “attention on” implies involvement, importance or concern; in a sense one is “right there with it”, *exclusively*. “Attention to” implies more of a distant or perhaps partial viewing. Examples:

> My attention was on my work.

> I paid attention to my work.

The first statement here is bolder, and implies complete fixity of focus.

> Focus your attention on this.

> Pay attention to this.

Again, the first statement is bolder and implies exclusivity. The second statement instructs is merely to take “this” in, whereas the first instructs us to pay full attention to it.

We can think of it through the direct meaning of the words, where “on” would mean on top of something, and “to” would mean more pointing towards something.

Comment: Thanks very much

Comment: No problem - if the answer was useful, you can mark it as correct (green tick) and/or upvote it (up arrow).

Comment: Done. I haven't had upvote rights untill recently. I did not realise that my voting privilage had been elivated, untill I tried to upvote this now.